# stack: download dependencies to repo to transfer on other machine

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like prepare a haskell project repository, currently using stack, such that it includes already all dependencies and stack can run without internet connection.

Background: The project directory shall be checked out on another machine, that has no internet connection, but which shall build and run the project.

I already considered copying the ~/.stack directory to that machine, but it seems to be quite linked to my machine (e.g. including local paths with my user name etc.).

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know how well this is currently supported. You may find some information in one of these issues: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+offline